# Verificación ReCaptcha de Google - validación boton

Tags: validación, botón

Tengo el siguiente código para activar el botón pero no me sirve, que tengo de mal?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>HTML Tutorial</title>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
        <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js'></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" onsubmit="return miFuncion(this)" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus/>
            <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le8P2cUAAAAAJC5S49UHp8z95JIpW31HSzbfVDN" data-callback="enabledSubmit"></div>
            <input type="submit"  name="enviar"  disabled />
        </form>
        <script>
        function enabledSubmit(response) {
            document.getElemenstByName('enviar')[0].disabled = false;
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: y que error te genera ?

Comment: La verdad no me genera nada, O sea no hace nada debería de activar el botón pero no hace nada

Answer (score 0):

Te falta cargar el javascript en el head:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=es" async defer></script>
```